# Repeat rows then manipulate those rows using data table in R

Tags: r, data.table

Hi I am new to data table syntax in R (and R in general) and need help to repeat certain rows and incrementally increased them based on category.

My mock data table information is below:

```
> head(dt)
       Time Values1 Values2 Values3 Category
1: 00:15:00       1       2     1.5        A
2: 00:30:00       3       4     2.5        A
3: 00:45:00       5       6     3.5        A
4: 01:00:00       7       8     4.5        A
5: 01:15:00       9      10     5.5        A
6: 01:30:00      11      12     6.5        A

> tail(dt)
       Time Values1 Values2 Values3 Category
1: 22:45:00     182     181    92.5        B
2: 23:00:00     184     183    93.5        B
3: 23:15:00     186     185    94.5        B
4: 23:30:00     188     187    95.5        B
5: 23:45:00     190     189    96.5        B
6: 00:00:00     192     191    97.5        B

> str(dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  192 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Time    :Class 'ITime'  int [1:192] 900 1800 2700 3600 4500 5400 6300 7200 8100 9000 ...
 $ Values1 : int  1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 ...
 $ Values2 : int  2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20 ...
 $ Values3 : num  1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5 10.5 ...
 $ Category: chr  "A" "A" "A" "A" ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

If the Category is A, I want to extrapolate each value (***highlighted yellow***) in the Time column to one minute while the remaining columns would still have the same values. **Note that**, if the time is 00:15, then my extrapolated section would have time from both 00:01 to 00:14 and 00:16 to 00:29, as shown below:

**---Goal---:**

[image]

If the category is B, then the time extrapolation is 5 minutes.

The final result will have the original data with all the time extrapolations and **no duplicated time values based on Category.**

****--- Thought Process----:****

My strategy is to break up into categories A and B, somehow find ways to add the extrapolated time and append them back to the original data table.

So far, I know how to break up into categories A and B, come up with a function to add minutes to the as.ITime type Time column and repeat each row in Time column

```
add_minutes <- function(m) {
  x <- m * 60
  return(x)
}

A <- dt[Category == 'A']
B <- dt[Category == 'B']

A <- A[,list(freq=rep(1,14)), by =.(Time,Values1,Values2,Values3,Category)][,freq:=NULL]
```

However, I do not know how to combine **add_minutes()** function to those repeated rows to:

1. Reset the time for each original time value
   .For example, if the original time is 00:30. I managed to repeat that line 14 times, then I want the 14 appearances of 00:30 to be a sequence from 00:31 to 00:44. If the original time is 00:45, then I want a sequence from 00:46 to 00:59, and so on.
2. Append this back to the original data table

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Comment: Please, provide the code to reproduce your dataset `dt`. I believe, the interesting parts are not `head()` or `tail()` but the middle part where `Category` switches from `A` to `B`. This is where the different answers need to be compared. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the *rolling join* as suggested by [pseudospin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63495630/3817004) will not return the expected result because `as.ITime("00:00:00")` is part of the time series `dt` and thus will be rolled forward to the additional time steps at `00:01:00`, `00:02:00`, `00:03:00`, etc. for `Category` `A`, or `00:05:00`, `00:10:00` for `Category` `B`, resp. (Note that `as.ITime("24:00:00") == as.ITime("00:00:00")`).

The approach below

1. creates all required time steps `completed_ts` for each `Category`
2. right joins with `dt` which adds many `NA`s to the values columns
3. fills the missing values for each `Category` by *last observation carried forward*,
4. and fills the missing values at the top of each `Category` by *next observation carried backward*, finally.

```
completed_ts <- rbind(
  data.table(Time = as.ITime(seq(1L, 1440L, 1L) * 60L), Category = "A"),
  data.table(Time = as.ITime(seq(5L, 1440L, 5L) * 60L), Category = "B")
)
res <- dt[completed_ts, on = .(Time, Category)]
cols <- paste0("Values", 1:3)
res[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, nafill, type = "locf"), .SDcols = cols, by = Category]
res[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, nafill, type = "nocb"), .SDcols = cols, by = Category]

# print interesting parts of the result
res[Category == "A", .SD[c(1:16, .N - 16:0)]]
res[Category == "B", .SD[c(1:4, .N - 4:0)]]
```

> ```
>         Time Values1 Values2 Values3 Category
>  1: 00:01:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  2: 00:02:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  3: 00:03:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  4: 00:04:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  5: 00:05:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  6: 00:06:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  7: 00:07:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  8: 00:08:00       1       2     1.5        A
>  9: 00:09:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 10: 00:10:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 11: 00:11:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 12: 00:12:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 13: 00:13:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 14: 00:14:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 15: 00:15:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 16: 00:16:00       1       2     1.5        A
> 17: 23:44:00     187     188    94.5        A
> 18: 23:45:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 19: 23:46:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 20: 23:47:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 21: 23:48:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 22: 23:49:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 23: 23:50:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 24: 23:51:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 25: 23:52:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 26: 23:53:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 27: 23:54:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 28: 23:55:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 29: 23:56:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 30: 23:57:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 31: 23:58:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 32: 23:59:00     189     190    95.5        A
> 33: 00:00:00     191     192    96.5        A
>         Time Values1 Values2 Values3 Category
> ```

> ```
>        Time Values1 Values2 Values3 Category
> 1: 00:05:00       2       1     2.5        B
> 2: 00:10:00       2       1     2.5        B
> 3: 00:15:00       2       1     2.5        B
> 4: 00:20:00       2       1     2.5        B
> 5: 23:40:00     188     187    95.5        B
> 6: 23:45:00     190     189    96.5        B
> 7: 23:50:00     190     189    96.5        B
> 8: 23:55:00     190     189    96.5        B
> 9: 00:00:00     192     191    97.5        B
> ```

Note that `data.tables`'s `nafill()` function only supports *double* and *integer* data types currently. If you need to fill other data types please see `zoo::na.locf()`.

#### Reproducible data

```
library(data.table)
dtA <- data.table(Time = seq(as.ITime("00:15:00"), by = 900L, length.out = 96L),
                  Values1 = seq(1L, by = 2L, length.out = 96L),
                  Values2 = seq(2L, by = 2L, length.out = 96L),
                  Values3 = seq(1.5, by = 1.0, length.out = 96L),
                  Category = rep("A", 96L))
dtB <- data.table(Time = seq(as.ITime("00:15:00"), by = 900L, length.out = 96L),
                  Values1 = seq(to = 192L, by = 2L, length.out = 96L),
                  Values2 = seq(to = 191L, by = 2L, length.out = 96L),
                  Values3 = seq(to = 97.5, by = 1.0, length.out = 96L),
                  Category = rep("B", 96L))

dt <- rbind(dtA, dtB)
```

Answer (score 0):

The magical rolling join in `data.table`.

```
desire <- rbind(
  data.table(Category = "A", Time = as.ITime(seq(1, 1440, 1)*60)),
  data.table(Category = "B", Time = as.ITime(seq(5, 1440, 5)*60))
)
dt[desire, on = c('Category','Time'), roll = TRUE, rollends = c(TRUE, TRUE)]
```

Comment: The answer does not return the expected result.

Comment: Downvote is a bit harsh given that it forms the basis a near one line answer to a difficult seeming problem. Anyway, isn't a better solution to the `00:00:00` problem just to acknowledge that you shouldn't have that in your input data in the first place and then the above works just fine.

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to rolling join in data.table, it's awesome!